# How to avoid onEdit timestamp when deleting cell content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having trouble with a script I'm trying to edit via the script gallery. I altered last updated script to have the time displayed in the active cell but the problem is I am unable to delete the cell content because deleting is a change in the active cell so the cell updates to the current time.

My code is below.

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 

  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  // note: actRng = the cell being updated
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var cindex = actRng.getColumnIndex();

  var dateCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(index,dateCol);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CST", "hh:mm:ss");

  actRng.setValue(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The `onEdit()` trigger is responding to you *editing* the cell, so as a workaround you simply need to change the content without actually editing it.

For example, *copy-pasting* content from a blank cell would not trigger the `onEdit()`.